# Method name expected and not null here C# error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code snippet that set Images in list view control.

```cs
delegate void SetImageListDataCallback(string imgName, int i);

void SetImageListData(string imgName, int i)
{
    if (lvFoundModelImages.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetImageListDataCallback c = new SetImageListDataCallback(imgName, i);
        this.Invoke(c, new object[]
        {
            imgName,i
        });
    }
    else
    {
        lvFoundModelImages.LargeImageList = imageList1;
        lvFoundModelImages.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(imgName, i));
    }
}
```

But the problem is I am getting errors in this line:

```cs
SetImageListDataCallback c = new SetImageListDataCallback(imgName, i);
```

in the first parameter,

> ImgName is not null here

. while the second parameter "i" showing

> method name expected

Comment: What do you expect that statement to do? The parameters in a delegate declaration are used when *invoking* the delegate, but your statement appears to be trying to create an *instance* of the delegate. Please read [my article on delegates and events](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Events) and see if that helps you.

Comment: (I suspect you just want `SetImageListDataCallback c = SetImageListData;` using a method group conversion.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong syntax to create a new instance of the `SetImageListDataCallback`. You should pass amethod with a matching signature as the first parameter of the delegate constructor:

```
SetImageListDataCallback c = new SetImageListDataCallback(SetImageListData);
```

Then, you can pass the imgName and i parameters as arguments at the invocation time:

```
this.Invoke(c, new object[] { imgName, i });
```

Comment: Note that there's no need to be quite as long-winded as this - just use a method group conversion: `SetImageListDataCallback c = SetImageListData;`